# How to deal with callbacks in ReactiveCocoa 5.0?

Tags: swift, swift3, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-5

**I have an utility class to handle the socket, and in the socket delegate methods i could know the current state of the socket, e.g. didConnected, didReadData and so on. I do not want to write an extra protocol with a delegate to send the socket state indeed.**

**Actually, there are 2 properties in my utility class, an enum to differentiate the current state of the socket between: didConnected, didReadData, didDisconnected, the other is a Data type value to store the received data from socket. It likes that:**

```
public enum SocketState {
    case unknown, didConnected, didReconnectedFailed, didSentHeartbeatPack, 
         didSentMessage, didReadData, didDisconnected
}
private var currentState: SocketState = .unknown
private var msgData = Data()
```

**After become the delegate of the socket, I have implemented the several methods,**

```
func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port: UInt16) {}
func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didWriteDataWithTag tag: Int) {}
func socketDidDisconnect(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, withError err: Error?) {}
```

What I intend to do is while I change the value of the ***currentState***, or I did set the received data to the ***msgData***, in my controller I could capture the **2** values changed simultaneously.

## How to make it by use ReactiveCocoa 5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved my goal by use the function "combineLatest" provided by ReactiveSwift.

First of all, announce two MutableProperty's variable, and one SignalProducer, likes below:

```
private var rac_state = MutableProperty<SocketState>(.unknown)
private var rac_msg = MutableProperty<Data>(Data())
public var rac_SocketStateChanged: SignalProducer<(SocketState, Data), NoError> {
    return SignalProducer.combineLatest(rac_state.producer, rac_msg.producer)
}
```

Then, change the **rac_state.value** or **rac_mas.value** in the socket delegate methods, likes that:

```
func socketDidDisconnect(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, withError err: Error?) {
    rac_state.value = .didDisconnected
}
```

Finally, make an observer in controller to listen the **combined SignalProducer**, here is the code:

```
func configTCPListen() {
    tcpManager.rac_SocketStateChanged
        .startWithValues { [weak self = self] (tuple) in
            switch tuple.0 {
            case .didDisconnected:
                print("TCP has disConnected!")
            default: break
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `MutableProperty` provided by **ReactiveSwift** could satisfies you. Your intension is very like what **KVO** mechanism can do in Objective-C, while Swift does not have. However, `MutableProperty` class implements the same functionality of which changes could be observed by someone.
Hope those below demos can make you understood the simplest way to use `MutableProperty` and its usage.

```
// definition
let currentState: MutableProperty<SocketState> = MutableProperty(.unknown)
let msgData: MutableProperty<Data> = MutableProperty(Data())

// observe changes
currentState.producer.startWithValues { state in
    // process(state)
}
msgData.producer.startWithValues { data in
    // doSomething(withData data)
}
```

If removed redundant explicit type inference, the above codes would be clean and simple.

```
// definition
let currentState = MutableProperty(.unknown)
let msgData = MutableProperty(Data())

// observe changes
currentState.producer.startWithValues {
    // process($0)
}
msgData.producer.startWithValues {
    // doSomething(withData $0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I have solved it. By the way, the KVO mechanism also exists in swift, you could add an observer for the keypath, than override the func `observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?){}`.

Comment: Sure, but you mentioned KVO mechanism is not pure swift, and who use it must be subclassed from NSObject. My answer missed some details, however, using `combineLatest` is absolute right.